# Plotly dates on x-axis not spaced appropriately

Tags: javascript, date, plotly

I'm trying to make a timeline plot that basically has no y-axis, just an x-axis with dates, and annotations showing when events occurred. I put dates in the x-values, but they are getting spaced evenly, rather than at the correct spacing (the dates (x-values) themselves are not spaced evenly).

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/98phb124/

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>
<div id="hoverinfo" style="margin-left:80px;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var hoverinfo = document.getElementById('hoverinfo');

var CA199 = 
    {
        x: ["7/1/2015","7/13/2015", "8/1/2015", "9/1/2015", "9/11/2015","10/1/2015"],
        y: ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
    type: 'linear',
    mode: 'markers'
    };

var data = [CA199];

var layout =
    {
        title: "Title",
        height: 0,
    xaxis:
    {
      tickfont:
      {
        color:"rgb(107, 107, 107)",
        size:11
      },
      ticks:"outside",
      tickwidth:1,
      tickangle:40,
      ticklen:5,
      showticklabels:true,
      showline:true,
      type:"scatter",
      autorange:true,
      tickmode:"auto",
      showgrid: false
        },
    yaxis:
    {
      autorange: true,
      showgrid: false,
      zeroline: false,
      autotick: false,
      ticks: '',
      showticklabels: false,
      showline: false,
    },
        annotations:
    [
      {
        x: "09/11/2015", 
        y: 0, 
        align: "center", 
        arrowcolor: "rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.53)", 
        arrowhead: 5, 
        arrowsize: 1, 
        ax: -0, 
        ay: -50, 
        bgcolor: "rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.29)", 
        bordercolor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", 
        borderpad: 3, 
        borderwidth: 0, 
        font: {size: 14}, 
        text: "CA12-3: 144", 
        textangle: 0
        }
        ]
    };

Plotly.plot
(
  'myDiv',
  data,
  layout,
  {scrollZoom: true}
);

myPlot
  .on('plotly_hover', function(data)
    {
      var infotext = data.points.map(function(d)
      {
        return (d.data.name+': x= '+d.x+', y= '+d.y.toPrecision(3));
      });
      hoverinfo.innerHTML = infotext.join('');
    })
  .on('plotly_unhover', function(data)
    {
        hoverinfo.innerHTML = '';
    });
```

Comment: I'm afraid that plotly doesn't support unevenly spaced ticks https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/wiki/Unsupported-plotly.js-features

Comment: I see. Are these perhaps in the hopper?

Comment: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/392

Comment: It's great that you created the issue on plotly's github. Have you seen their answer? It turns out that plotly can do what you need. Apparently, the table of unsupported features that I referenced is outdated. By the way, what is the hopper?

Comment: Yes, I was getting ready to comment to you that someone on the plotly forum showed me how to do it, and update the issue. "[In the hopper](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+hopper)" is an American (or perhaps English speaking) saying meaning "something being worked on that will soon arrive." As in, there is a machine where you put things to be worked on in a [hopper](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hopper+definition), then they come out when they are done.

Comment: Haha, and I was searching for hopper.js and thinking that it's yet another charting library ;) Thanks for explanation!